# How to get product's ID after add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I'm observing the event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, and I need to get the product's ID. I'm not sure how to do that.

My current code so far is something like this:

```
public static function stockUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    # Get event
    $order = $observer->getEvent();

    # Do stuff
}
```

The point of this is to verify if that product is still available in a third-party webservice.

Comment: Any reason why you're using a static function?

Comment: not really.....

Comment: Then don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

*If you wanna **prevent add to cart when product isn't available**  at **third-party webservice***

Then  you **should use**  event `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after` and it will be work for ***frontend and adminhtml both**

> Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_item_qty_set_after', array('item' =>
>   $this));

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
/* @var $quoteItem Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
if (!$quoteItem || !$quoteItem->getProductId() || !$quoteItem->getQuote()
    || $quoteItem->getQuote()->getIsSuperMode()) {
    return $this;
}
$product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
if([ThirtCheckError]){
    $quoteItem->addErrorInfo(
                'cataloginventory',
                Mage_CatalogInventory_Helper_Data::ERROR_QTY,
                Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('You cannot checkout this  item.')
    );
}
```

---

**OLd**

add observer add below code  for prevent add

**`checkout_cart_product_add_after`** event is worked  only at frontend.

At **`checkout_cart_product_add_after`** event,you will get two parameter,first current get current quote item from  **`$quoteItem= $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()`**.
and get product object **`$product= $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()`**

> Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after',
>   array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));

Comment: Can you please tell me if there are better events to watch for my purpose?

Comment: when you  want to check product available at **third-party webservice** before cart or  during Cart or  after cart.? Want prevent cart when  product does not available at **third-party webservice**?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wanna prevent add to cart when product isn't available

Comment: It worked, but for some reason when I call a method in helper Data.php it returns null :( but thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$productId = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();
```

But please don't make the observer function static.

Comment: I'll try, thanks. Why not? Please, I'm new to Magento

Comment: Because the observer class gets instantiated in order to call the function.

Comment: @Stordon, it's not about Magento, but general OOP principles. Observer is called in the object context, but stating the method as static you move it to another field of visibility. Your method will be called and executed, sure. But if you try to access any non-static property or method you'll get error message.

Comment: @Marius not exactly. This observer method will be executed without error, but in static context. Btw, one of the main classes of Magento 1 is Varien_Object uses __call() method as Set/Get attribute wrapper. It works only for object context and __callStatic() method is not implemented. And if there won't be an error in this call, any other usage of the static can cause misfunctioning  of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
$productId = $product->getId();
```